# when I create a react app project with the create reaction app's npm command, my react devTool showing red

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a doubt, when I create a react app project with the create reaction app's npm command `npm init react-app my-app`, it opens on the web page, why is my react devTool showing red? I just want to develop version debugging.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khcXm.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are in development mode and the dev extension give you a warning saying that is not a production build.This is not a problem if you are developing just make sure that when you deploy you have a production build.
See instructions [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build)

Comment: But when I open the Google Chrome Developer Tools, it doesn't show up.so it made me a bit confused.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, let me see the official document.

Comment: No worries if you are using webpack you can run webpack --mode production